# Index Match - Removing Blanks From Table Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is what was posted from the formula sorting the numbers from the blanks

[image]

The original table columns with blanks
[image]

I don't know why it has done this for this one column, its worked on every other column in the table except for this one. Just curious as to why excel isn't completing the formula properly.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Q137:Q151,SMALL(IF(Q137:Q151<>"",ROW(Q137:Q151)-ROW(Q136)),ROW()-ROW(Q136))),"")}
```

Comment: A quick guess (as the details are not clear) is that you dragged the formula down and the cell references moved as well, have you tried Q$137:Q151 etc?

Comment: as @SolarMike points out all your instances of Q137:Q151 should be: Q$137:Q151. So your formula should look like: 

`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Q$137:Q151,SMALL(IF(Q$137:Q151<>"",ROW(Q$137:Q151)-ROW(Q136)),ROW()-ROW(Q136))),"")}`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, what I did was select all of the cells and paste the formula into the formula bar. I tried to update the formula with the $before the first row, however it still didn't sort them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm an idiot and had a space in the cell all along, I apologize....

The formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(N137:N151,SMALL(IF(N137:N151<>"",ROW(N137:N151)-ROW(N136)),ROW()-ROW(N136))),"")}
```

(with the "N136" always being the cell right before your actual list of data begins)

Works as an amazing function to remove blank cells from a row in order to expand into other features such as a Dynamic Named Range, which is great for graphs and a automatic data validation list.